# How to get cell indexvalues by using contentview components in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi in my application I added switch on cell contentview. Now if i select that switch the particular cell index values have to get. For that I wrote the code as such below in switch selector method.

```
UISwitch *_switch = (UISwitch *)sender ;
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[_switch superview] superview];
```

Here I have many sections and each section having many rows.In ios6 if I select any switch it's giving that particular cell tag value correctly. But in ios7 It is always returning first row of first section values even If i select any switch also.

Log message is as such below in IOS7 :

Cell is 0

Cell is ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Please let me know how to resolve this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: What happens if we can't get you an answer to this problem immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a custom UITableViewCell subclass, with a delegate method for the switch action.  Then its not dependant on the view hierarchy which is different on iOS6/7 Something like:

```
@protocol SwitchCellDelegate;
@interface SwitchCell : UITableViewCell

- (IBAction)switched:(id)sender;
@end

@protocol SwitchCellDelegate

- (void)switchCell:(SwitchCell *)cell didSwitch:(BOOL)switchState;

@end
```